# Postgres Composite Primary Key Dependency Issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I'm taking a database course at Johns Hopkins in Maryland and have a question. I already emailed my professor and he knows I'm asking this question here and he's cool with that. So I'm developing a COOKBOOK DB in Postgres and I have an interesting problem I’ve been facing in Postgres where I just can’t seem to be able to build the PRICE table. I have a nice Cookbook ERD but apparently can't post until my reputation is at least 10. I'll do my best to describe the ERD. There are three factoring tables relating to PRICE. These are INGREDIENT, SUBSTITUTION, and PRICE.

Here's a link to the ERD (notice the 1:M for INGREDIENT to SUBSTITUTION):
[[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEExS.jpg)]

I can have one INGREDIENT with potentially many SUBSTITUTIONS and a possible one-to-one between SUBSTITUTION and PRICE (one PRICE per SUBSTITUTION if a PRICE is known). If the PRICE is known then the PRICE is able to define a tuple with a composite primary key: (price_id, ingredient_id (fk), substitution_id (fk))

The challenge I’m facing is that Postgres SQL is not allowing me to establish this relationship and I’m not exactly sure why. I’ve set the keys in SUBSTITUTION to have a UNIQUE constraint so that shouldn’t be the problem. The only thing I can think of is that the ingredient_id in SUBSTITUTION is a foreign key to INGREDIENT and therefore may not be physically established in SUBSTITUTION but the error I'm getting doesn't suggest that. This is what I’m getting in the terminal (**first describing SUBSTITUTION**):

```
   cookbook=# \d+ SUBSTITUTION
                                                             Table "public.substitution"
   Column       |         Type          |                                Modifiers                                 | Storage  | Description 
   --------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
   substitution_id    | integer               | not null default nextval('subsitution_substitution_id_seq'::regclass)    | plain    | 
   ingredient_id      | integer               | not null default nextval('subsitution_ingredient_id_seq'::regclass)      | plain    | 
   name               | character varying(50) | not null                                                                 | extended | 
   measurement_ref_id | integer               | not null default nextval('subsitution_measurement_ref_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
   metric_unit        | character varying(25) | not null                                                                 | extended | 
   Indexes:
   "subsitution_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (substitution_id, ingredient_id)
   "uniqueattributes" UNIQUE, btree (substitution_id, ingredient_id)
   Foreign-key constraints:
   "subsitution_ingredient_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id) REFERENCES ingredient(ingredient_id)
   "subsitution_measurement_ref_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (measurement_ref_id) REFERENCES measurement_ref(measurement_ref_id)
   Has OIDs: no

   cookbook=# create table price(
   price_id serial not null,
   ingredient_id serial references substitution(ingredient_id),
   cookbook(# substitution_id serial references substitution(substitution_id),
   cookbook(# usdollars smallint not null,
   cookbook(# availability season,
   cookbook(# seasonal boolean,
   cookbook(# primary key (price_id, ingredient_id, substitution_id)
   cookbook(# );
   NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "price_price_id_seq" for serial column "price.price_id"
   NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "price_ingredient_id_seq" for serial column "price.ingredient_id"
   NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "price_substitution_id_seq" for serial column "price.substitution_id"
   NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "price_pkey" for table "price"
   ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "substitution"
```

Comment: I don't know if i really understood, A foreign key must be unique in its own table, if you want to reference the tuple: substitition_id and ingredient_id, you can add a column something like `ingredient_subtition_id` as serial into your `substitution` table, and make it primary key, this key can be referenced as foreign key from the `price` table.

Comment: @Houari Adding a key & FK does not stop there being the constraint from PRICE (substitution_id, ingredient_id) to SUBSTITUTION. All your suggestion does is have a FK exist but without the effect that is the point of the original desired constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've omitted some columns, so you can focus on the keys. I barely glanced at your ERD. (I hate ERDs with the burning passion of a thousand suns.)

```
create table ingredients (
  ingredient_id serial primary key,
  -- Don't allow duplicate names. 
  ingredient_name varchar(35) not null unique
);

create table substitutions (
  -- These are properly declared integer, not serial. 
  -- Also note two separate foreign key references.
  ingredient_id integer not null references ingredients (ingredient_id),
  substitute_id integer not null references ingredients (ingredient_id),
  primary key (ingredient_id, substitute_id)
);

create table prices (
  -- Price id number is unnecessary.
  ingredient_id integer not null,
  substitute_id integer not null,
  -- Money is usually declared numeric(n, m) or decimal(n, m).
  us_dollars numeric(10, 2) not null 
    -- Negative amounts don't make sense.
    check (us_dollars >= 0),
  -- Only one row per distinct substitution.
  primary key (ingredient_id, substitute_id),
  -- One single foreign key reference, but it references *two* columns.
  foreign key (ingredient_id, substitute_id) references substitutions (ingredient_id, substitute_id)
);
```

Comment: I take back my original comment. Yes this worked. I'll post an update. Your SQL for the SUBSTITUTE and INGERDIENTS is off a tad but yes the create table for PRICE is spot on. Also when you name tables it's good practice to name them singular not plural (e.g. PRICE not PRICES).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `FOREIGN KEY` defined in the `price` table, `substitution(ingredient_id)`, is not unique.

In the `substitution` table, you have the following indexes defined:

```
  "subsitution_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (substitution_id, ingredient_id)
   "uniqueattributes" UNIQUE, btree (substitution_id, ingredient_id)
```

This means that for that table uniqueness currently requires a *tuple* of `(substitution_id, ingredient_id)`. As an aside, those two indexes are really duplicates of each other, since a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint guarantees uniqueness by defintion.

So, you have a variety of options, but I find the easiest thing to do is often use a single unique ID which is defined for every table -- I like to use `id serial`, which will create an implicit sequence, and then define that to be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Then you can use just that key to define `FOREIGN KEY`  relationships. While doing that with multi-key tuples, it certainly complicates things, and I find using a single ID easier. You can always create additional unique indexes on multi-key tuples if you need those for `SELECT` performance, etc.

The same thing applies to the FK constraint on `ingredient_id` -- it's not unique. The same type of remedy I mentioned above applies to that column also.

Comment: Well I would love to implement that single PK. That would be nice but I'm constrained (no pun) to apply the multiple keys to conform to my ERD design. He doesn't want us to cut any corners but I agree your method is the one I would implement in the real world (yes I do some DB work). I tried the following to ensure the ingredient_id is unique as you suggested:alter table ingredient add constraint uniqueingredientid UNIQUE(ingredient_id); hoping to resolve the issue and am still getting the same "not unique" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say that the single PK method is "cutting corners" -- I think it's actually more the opposite, since it's essentially an extra rather than just using the multi-key tuple. Does the assignment explicitly forbid single PKs? Can you actually add the `UNIQUE` constraint on `ingredient`, and then the error comes on the FK in `substitution`?

Comment: Yeah I can't do it that way. Need to follow strict ERD design with composite keys. Managed to resolve the issues. Check out my answer. I'll play around with this tomorrow to ensure 1NF, 2NF, and 3NF.

Comment: @JasonRice & khampson Adding a key & FK does not stop there being the constraint from PRICE (substitution_id, ingredient_id) to SUBSTITUTION. All your suggestion does is have a FK exist but without the effect that is the point of the original desired constraint.

Answer (score -2):

** UPDATE: 2014-11-02 decided to just drop the PRICE table. My professor said that it would be fine to absorbe two separate price attributes into the INGREDIENT and SUBSTITUTION entity types. He said I was thinking to hard as I often do. **

**Problem Solved! Thanks everyone for all the feedback.** This site is really good. Here's the final solution layout:

Building the INGREDIENT, SUBSTITUTION, and PRICE in that order...

```
   create table INGREDIENT(
      ingredient_id serial not null,
      description text,
      amount smallint,
      measurement_ref_id serial references measurement_ref(measurement_ref_id),
      nutritional_info_id serial references nutritional_info(nutritional_info_id),
      primary key (ingredient_id)
   );

   create table SUBSTITUTION(
      substitution_id serial not null unique,
      ingredient_id serial not null references ingredient(ingredient_id),
      name varchar(50) not null,
      measurement_ref_id serial references measurement_ref(measurement_ref_id),
      metric_unit varchar(25) not null,
      primary key (substitution_id, ingredient_id)
   );

   -- NOTE: I'll add the other variables to this later.
   CREATE TABLE PRICE(
      ingredient_id serial not null,
      substitution_id serial not null,
      -- link the two keys from substitution in as two unique foreign keys
      foreign key (ingredient_id, substitution_id) references substitution (ingredient_id, substitution_id),   
      -- combine foreign keys as one single composite primary key
      primary key (ingredient_id, substitution_id)
   );
```

If anyone is interested I'm putting up a github and linking in all my SQL scripts. I'm making a COOKBOOK database with an ERD and 12 tables. Should be a fun project. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Stil wrong. The {ingredient_id,substitution_id} in the PRICE table should be `INTEGER NOT NULL` not `serial` They just refer to the PKs of the INGREDIENT and SUBSTITUTION tables.

Comment: @wildplasser I decided not to go with this route. I think I'll end up removing this post sometime down the road.